# How to mail data from HTML form after it's checked by recaptcha?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm working on a contact website, where I want to have contact form. I want it to send data to e-mail and I want it to be checked by Google's recaptcha v3.

This is my second try. In the past, I've done it successfully without recaptcha. Now, I used this (https://codeforgeek.com/google-recaptcha-v3-tutorial/) tutorial, with following result:

script below the form

```
       // when form is submit
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        // we stoped it
        event.preventDefault();
        var mail = $('#email').val();
        var comment = $("#sprava").val();
        // needs for recaptacha ready
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            // do request for recaptcha token
            // response is promise with passed token
            grecaptcha.execute('__SITE-KEY__', {action: 'create_comment'}).then(function(token) {
                // add token to form
                $('#myform').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="' + token + '">');
                    $.post("form.php",{mail: mail, comment: comment, token: token}, function(result) {
                            if(result.success) {
                                    alert('Thanks for message')
                            } else {
                                    alert('An error occured')
                            }
                    });
            });;
        });
  });
  </script>
```

the names of html form fields are "email", "vyber", "sprava"

form.php

```
<?php
  $mail;$comment;$captcha;
  $mail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mail', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
  $comment = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comment', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $captcha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'token', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  }

  function email_sending(){
    $webmaster_email = "bla@bla.com";
    $sender_email= "blabla@bla.com" ;

    $email_address = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $selection = $_REQUEST['vyber'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['sprava'];

    $msg =
    "E-mail: " . $email_address . "\r\n" .
    "I'm interested in " . $selection . "\r\n" .
    "Message: " . $message ;


    mail( "$webmaster_email", "You have mail", $msg, $header);
  }

  if($responseKeys["success"]) {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 'true'));
    email_sending();
  } else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 'false'));
  }
?>
```

The problem isn't within recaptcha part, but then I recieve e-mail, where data is missing. (it shows only variable names, not actual values). I might think it's because of naming in script, as I'm not sure what to write in declaration of variables. I'd be glad to receive any input about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by changing server-side code like below, thanks to this [Recaptcha tutorial](https://stevencotterill.com/articles/adding-google-recaptcha-v3-to-a-php-form).

```
  // Check if form was submitted:
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['recaptcha_response'])) {

// Build POST request:
$recaptcha_url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$recaptcha_secret = '__SECRET-KEY___';
$recaptcha_response = $_POST['recaptcha_response'];

// Make and decode POST request:
$recaptcha = file_get_contents($recaptcha_url . '?secret=' . $recaptcha_secret . '&response=' . $recaptcha_response);
$recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);

// Take action based on the score returned:
if ($recaptcha->success == true) {
    // Verified - send email

} else {
    // Not verified - show form error

}
```

}